# Has the word "phenomena" become a singular noun: even on mainstream media it is often used as if it is

Tags: grammatical-number, loan-words

This text was written by [coffee1054](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13752) in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/please-show-me-my-mistakes):

> The phenomena of superconductivity was discovered in 1911.

Is the sentence above acceptable, or should it be changed to "phenomenon"?  I rarely hear the singular form these days.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is adequately addressed here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53033/phenomena-as-singular-usage, but in short, the answer is **no** - the increasing misuse of the word phenomena has not (yet at least) tipped the scales towards accepted usage.